# Can view a URL through a browser but not with CURL

Tags: php, forms, curl, http-status-code-404

I ran into an interesting issue today when I was working on an application I'm developing. Hopefully someone knows why this is happening / how to adjust my work flow for it!

**Background:**
I'm writing an application that helps students at universities get in touch with each other. The basic workflow is as follows:

> 1. User registers for the service
> 2. The application uses CURL to poll the university directory for their name
> 3. Store their contact info in a database table

My test site is the Rutgers University directory (http://www.acs.rutgers.edu/directory) 
I can access the service fine through my browser (Posts to http://www.acs.rutgers.edu/pls/pdb_p/Pdb_Display.search_results), but if I try to post the same information via CURL, I get a 404 error.

*Note:* I get the same error if I open that url directly from a browser and don't use their form to submit the data.

**Code:**
Here is the code they use on the directory site:

```
<fieldset>
<legend>Search For People</legend>
<div style="width:50%;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;">
<form method="post" action="http://www.acs.rutgers.edu/pls/pdb_p/Pdb_Display.search_results" name="thisform" onkeyup="highlight()" onclick="highlight()">
    <p>
        <label for="p_name_last">Last Name:&nbsp;&nbsp;[Required]</label><br>
        <input tabindex="1" accesskey="L" class="required" type="text" id="p_name_last" name="p_name_last" size="25" maxlength="23">
    </p> 
    <p>
        <label for="p_name_first">First Name:&nbsp;&nbsp;[or initial]</label><br> 
        <input tabindex="2" accesskey="f" type="text" id="p_name_first" name="p_name_first" size="25" maxlength="23"> 
    </p>
    <input tabindex="3" type="submit" value="Search">&nbsp;&nbsp;
</form>
</div>
```

And here is the code I am using to CURL the service:

```
<?php
$p_name_last = "doe";
$p_name_first = "";
$curlPost = 'p_name_last='  . urlencode($p_name_last) . '&p_name_first=' . urlencode($p_name_first) . '&SUBMIT=Search';
$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.acs.rutgers.edu/pls/pdb_p/Pdb_Display.search_results');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $curlPost); 
if( ! $result = curl_exec($ch)) 
{ 
    trigger_error(curl_error($ch)); 
} 
curl_close($ch); 
echo "<pre>";
print_r($result); 
?>
```

Any thoughts or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks,
Mike

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Web servers can choose what response to send after processing the request. That'll be why you are seeing the 404 - there's a resource there but it's responding in a unintuitive manner.

Anyway, I can post with curl to this page and get a response;

`curl http://www.acs.rutgers.edu/pls/pdb_p/Pdb_Display.search_results --data-urlencode p_name_last=test --data-urlencode p_name_first=test`

If I post with your SUBMIT=... param I get a 404. Try it with just the two name parameters.

---

Update: in fact, you can send just the last name parameter so long as the first name parameter is present - the first name parameter can be empty.

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be that the form's input element

```
<input tabindex="3" type="submit" value="Search">
```

contains no name attribute, hence is not sent along in the POST data in the form `SUBMIT=search`, or at least it shouldn't be, according to http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_name.asp, where it is stated that

*"Only form elements with a name attribute will have their values passed when submitting a form."*

I suppose your attempt resulted in a 404 response because the script accepting your request never expects a `SUBMIT` variable, and that's why the accepted solution works.

Comment: I'm afraid you have misinterpreted. `<input type="submit">` is the submit button whose value is not submitted. It just initiates the `POST`. That said, the wording used by [W3Fools](http://w3fools.com) is ambiguous, i.e. "form elements" should be thought of as the "form values" or "form data" from other input types, rather than HTML elements themselves. Furthermore, the [HTML Specification](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1866#section-8.1.2.7) specifies that `name` is an optional attribute of `<input type="submit">`.

Answer (score 0):

check your browser proxy setting. 
I had the same problem. It turned out it was caused by my proxy setting, which directed the request to the proxy server.

Answer (score -1):

Indeed page http://www.acs.rutgers.edu/pls/pdb_p/Pdb_Display.search_results do not exists.
You have redirection to New Address: http://eas.rutgers.edu, browser can follow redirection but CURL might have a problem with it.

The web page you are trying to reach has moved!

New Address: http://eas.rutgers.edu

Please remember to update your bookmarks.

This page will automatically redirect in 10 seconds.
If redirect fails, click http://eas.rutgers.edu to continue.

The web page you are trying to reach has moved!

New Address: http://eas.rutgers.edu

Please remember to update your bookmarks.

This page will automatically redirect in 10 seconds.
If redirect fails, click http://eas.rutgers.edu to continue.

Comment: URL you provided in 6th line of your PHP file was 404,.. that is all what I wanted to tell you. Thx for putting me down for that.

Comment: The whole point was that it wasn't really a 404... read lines 10-13 of my post.